# error while running ionic ios build --prod --release (@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3)

Tags: ionic2

I ran the following command:

```
ionic ios build --prod --release
```

And received the following error:

```
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module d:/ionic/event/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
            at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24474:34)
            at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24260:46)
            at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24241:14)
            at d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23023:30
            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at extractProgramSymbols (d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23022:79)
            at AotCompiler.compileAll (d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22720:47)
            at CodeGenerator.codegen (d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:30:14)
            at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:61:30)
            at d:\ionic\event\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:182:73
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "3.14.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "1.4.5",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "~2.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is and you gave very little context

Comment: Please show errors formatted as code and not as plain text. Furthermore, calls to action ("Please help me") won't make people help you faster, especially if they are crying.

Comment: Placed command into question body, followed by error, followed by dependencies.  Changed "help" into "What am I doing wrong?"